# Alignment and Gradients

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, alignment

I am pretty new to Photoshop and am trying to do 2 things. I'm pretty sure this is the right site for this question.

How do I horizontally and vertically center a Layer, or Text or an Image on the canvas, and how do I give Text a multi colored gradient, as shown in the picture below?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Horizontal and Vertical Alignment

Regarding your first question, you can't actually **vertically** align text inside a layer. What you do instead is [**explained in the first answer to this question**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26212/how-to-center-text-vertically-within-a-textbox-in-photoshop), that I think is very valid for any type of element:

> For positioning text you don't need a bounding box. I never use
>   bounding boxes for text in PS. I click the text tool without dragging
>   and set the text cursor without a box. Once the text is entered, I can
>   center it vertically or horizontally just like any other shape using
>   the align buttons--assuming I have something to align it to.

So basically what you move around and align using the alignment tools is the **layer** rather than the text inside a textbox. If you want to use a textbox still, there is a [**workaround using baseline shift**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/26219/2857).

For the **horizontal** alignment, you just need to use `Center Text` in the `Paragraph` panel.

But as mentioned, for all layers (be it text, shape, etc), you should use the `Align` tools. You can find a nice guide on [**how to get you started with alignment** in the Adobe site](http://helpx.adobe.com/en/photoshop/using/aligning-layers.html).

### Gradient Overlay

Now about your second question, the gradient. The easiest thing you can probably do is just use `Blending Options > Gradient Overlay`. Now if you want all your texts to have the exact same gradient regardless of size, you could:

- Draw a rectangle the same size as the expected text;
- Apply a multiple-color gradient to the rectangle;
- Use the gradient layer as a layer mask so only the letters show the colors.

A quick example of these options. In the first one the gradient adapts to the length of the word, in the second it remains the same.

[image]

Note: This is killing my eyes too.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

## Use shortcuts!

I can recommend you to use align tools shortcuts. enter preformatted text hereIf you get used to using it, it's pretty fast! 
Just go **Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts** then open the **Layer** bookmark and then find **Align** (it's somewhere down) and after this just set **Vertical Centers** and **Horizontal Centers** on some keys (i recommend Command+W and Command+D)

Hope this'll improve your workflow.