# Auto center in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, alignment, button

Is there any way to auto center button and text Photoshop? so when i change the size of the text i wont need to re-align it manually in the button.
Many thanks!

Comment: Do either of the below answer your question?  If they do not please make an [edit] with more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Photoshop if you look into Photoshop scripting.  You do not indicate what version of Photoshop you're using but [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html) is the documentation for multiple versions of Photoshop.

If your target button is on a layer you could do something like:

```
theButton = app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName("button");
```

and then target the text with something along the lines of:

```
.textItem.Justification.CENTER;
```

[image]

If you are not wanting to go the scripting route I would encourage you to use InDesign as this is what is best suited for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not in Photoshop. In layout applications such as InDesign and Scribus this is generally possible.

What you can do however is put the text in a text box the width of the button. But vertical alignment doesn't exist (see: [How to center text vertically within a textbox in Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26212/how-to-center-text-vertically-within-a-textbox-in-photoshop)).

There are ways to make it a little more efficient using the alignment buttons but nothing that will automatically do what you're after.